# Hide within a If Function

Tags: excel, if-statement

I would like to use the hide function depending upon the selection made in another cell, such as actual and forecast result, in a If Function, can this be done in Excel 2010.

Comment: No. As a general rule, functions called from the worksheet -- even user-defined functions -- cannot manipulate the worksheet or its objects.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a block of cells that display data that is only relevant once we have actual data as opposed to forecast data.

One way to "hide" these cells is to use Conditional Formatting with the FormulaIs option.  Just set the colour of the font equal to the colour of the cell background.